# Adding an achor to a aspx page and getting the domainname

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to add an anchor that pulls in the domain name and then i can just have whatever after that for example

```
<a href="GET_THE_DOMAIN+/admin/pages/customers/add.aspx">ADD CUSTOMERS</a>
```

how can I get the domain without hardcoding it since we will be using the same website but in different domains with different content, in other words the only thing changing is the domain

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use an absolute link *without* the domain?

```
<a href="/admin/pages/customers/add.aspx">ADD CUSTOMERS</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a base page that all of your aspx pages inherit from and in that base page add the following function:

```
 public string RootUrl(bool includeAppPath = false)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var port = context.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
        if (port == null || port == "80" || port == "443")
        {
            port = "";
        } else
        {
            port = ":" + port;
        }
        var protocol = context.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"];
        if (protocol == null || protocol == "0")
        {
            protocol = "http://";
        }else
        {
            protocol = "https://";
        }
        var appPath = "";
        if (includeAppPath)
        {
            appPath = context.Request.ApplicationPath;
            if (appPath == "/")
                appPath = "";
        }

        var sOut = protocol + context.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + port + appPath + "/";
        return sOut;
    }
```

Then in your anchor tags you could call that function as follows:

```
 <a href='<%= RootUrl() %>/admin/pages/customers/add.aspx'>ADD CUSTOMERS</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

`<a href="<%=Request.Url.Host%>/admin/pages/customers/add.aspx">ADD CUSTOMERS</a>`

Having said that, why can't you just use an absolute URL without the domain?

Comment: Don't you mean relative (not absolute)